# Ideas on how to handle a javascript widget?

Tags: javascript, xml, widget

My friend has a search engine that he wants to have a widget access that can be put on other web pages. If I send a request to the search engine, it returns an XML file. The request would look something like this:
    http://www.site.com/page.php?keyword=this+is+a+sample&page=1&num_days=3&source_id=site2.com&source_name=site2&source_url=sampleurl.php

I understand how to access this by using Javascript. However, I know that you can't do a cross-domain request. I would have to have it load a new page at the search engines's site and not in the window at the the site they were located at....right? Any ideas or insight are greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSONP to the rescue. Check [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/?ca=dgr-jw64JSONP-jQuery&S_TACT=105AGY46&S_CMP=grsitejw64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good explanation too:

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)

**EDIT:**

> **jsonpString**
>
> Override the callback function name in
>   a jsonp request. This value will be
>   used instead of `callback` in the
>   `callback=?` part of the query string
>   in the url. So `{jsonp:'onJsonPLoad'}`
>   would result in 'onJsonPLoad=?' passed
>   to the server.

> **jsonpCallbackString**
>
> Specify the callback function name for
>   a jsonp request. This value will be
>   used instead of the random name
>   automatically generated by jQuery. It
>   is preferable to let jQuery generate a
>   unique name as it'll make it easier to
>   manage the requests and provide
>   callbacks and error handling. You may
>   want to specify the callback when you
>   want to enable better browser caching
>   of GET requests.

taken from:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If using this method, would I be able to use jQuery instead? I am assuming not since it is still going cross-browser.