# How to parse xml data which is get by jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing, jsonp

I want get xml data by across domain, so in the `$.ajax` method I set the `dataType` to `jsonp`(the `crossDomain` parameter is useless),just like:

```
app.getData = function (url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (xml) {
            console.log('data', xml);
            //var data = $.parseXML(xml);
            //console.log('data', data);
        }
    })
}
```

Good news is I can get the data correctly, through check the `HttpRequest` response data.Bad news is the xml I get can not be print or parse through browser or javascript.

So how can I get and print the data?

Comment: You are setting the daType as jsonp. What is the ouput if you do `console.log(xml);` in your success handler

Comment: The chrome told me:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: What is the jsonp url returning?

Comment: @Chandu:it return xml, just like:`<?xml version="1.0"?><books><book><id>441</id><title_sc>......`

Comment: That could be the issue. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435454/using-jsonp-when-returning-xml

Comment: I am having the same problem. Chrome is preventing the response from getting to the jquery library, because it (Chrome) doesnt like the > character there.