# GWT receive xml as JSONP from cross domain

Tags: cordova, servlets, gwt, jsonp

I'm trying to create web-scraping functionality for my GWT app.  This involves making HTTP requests from the client, which violates SOP.  You can circumvent this by using JSONP, if the other domain is sending JSONP responses.  I'm wanting to make a request to `www.google.com` (for example) and scrap the html.  What I'm wondering is this: Is there a way to wrap a `GET` request to an html-serving domain in JSONP? This way I would be able to make requests without using a proxy server.

Note: If anyone is wondering why I can't use a proxy server it's because I want this to be a completely client-side app, eventually to become a phonegap app.

From what I have read, there is no way to do this without adding some server-side code, is this true?

Comment: SOP = [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to retrieve other content-type than JSON through a JSONP request.

Well, I don't know of existing solutions for this case. JSONP relies on script element injection, forcing your retrieved data to be javascript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Script_element_injection).

Additional references:

[Use JSONP to load an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531823/use-jsonp-to-load-an-html-page)

[Using JSONP when returning XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435454/using-jsonp-when-returning-xml)

Comment: Good informative resources.  The next thing I would look into is using CORS with GWT.